# C# Registry ObjectDisposedException Cases

Tags: c#, registry, objectdisposedexception

I'm writing an application that accesses the Windows registry in C#.

My question on a high level is: **Are there any circumstances that would cause an ObjectDisposedException be thrown when using `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key)`?**

This code would only be run under Administrative privileges in my application and the key is a constant that will never be null. My first instinct would be that an ObjectDisposedException would never be thrown by this static call because the MSDN document ([linked here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128501(v=vs.110).aspx) states that it would only be thrown when the RegistryKey is closed but I can't find in the MSDN whether or not it is possible to ever run into a closed RegistryKey through the static call.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Weird, its almost as if this could be tested on your own

Comment: what if you call `Close` or `Dispose` on it

Comment: @DanielA.White The call would only ever be used to read a value, I wasn't intending to call `Close` or `Dispose` on it since it was a static call, also I thought closing wouldn't work on members of `Registry`, such as `LocalMachine`.

Comment: if its the same type, then you should treat it as other instances.

Comment: @maccettura I was trying to figure out a way to test this, and reading through the documentation I was unable to figure out an example that would work. I posted the question in case there were edge cases that aren't as obvious. My tests so far haven't been able to produce the exception, but it's also difficult to test for situations that I may be unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is this:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.Close();
Registry.LocalMachine.Dispose();
var hardwareKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HARDWARE");
```

`Registry.LocalMachine` returns a `RegistryKey`. If you can actually close and/or dispose it then the following line should throw an exception, which it won't.

If you do the same thing with another registry key - close it and then try to open a subkey, it will throw an `ObjectDisposedException`.

```
var hardwareKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HARDWARE");
hardwareKey.Close();
// throws the exception.
var descriptionKey = hardwareKey.OpenSubKey("DESCRIPTION");
```

Why do they behave differently?

According to [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/registrykey.cs,adf4c8eba8366745), `RegistryKey.Close` calls `Dispose`. But the particular `RegistryKey` returned by `Registry.LocalMachine` will never be closed.

This isn't documented (other than the source code) **so it's up to you whether you want to rely on it**. But it makes sense that if you're accessing the registry key via a static method then you shouldn't be able to close/dispose it.

If you follow the logic, system keys (including `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`) will not be disposed except for `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA`.

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (hkey != null)
    {
        if (!IsSystemKey())
        {
            try
            {
                hkey.Dispose();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                // we don't really care if the handle is invalid at this point
            }
            finally
            {
                hkey = null;
            }
        }
        else if (disposing && IsPerfDataKey())
        {
            // System keys should never be closed.  However, we want to call RegCloseKey
            // on HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA when called from PerformanceCounter.CloseSharedResources
            // (i.e. when disposing is true) so that we release the PERFLIB cache and cause it
            // to be refreshed (by re-reading the registry) when accessed subsequently. 
            // This is the only way we can see the just installed perf counter.  
            // NOTE: since HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA is process wide, there is inherent ---- in closing
            // the key asynchronously. While Vista is smart enough to rebuild the PERFLIB resources
            // in this situation the down level OSes are not. We have a small window of ---- between  
            // the dispose below and usage elsewhere (other threads). This is By Design. 
            // This is less of an issue when OS > NT5 (i.e Vista & higher), we can close the perfkey  
            // (to release & refresh PERFLIB resources) and the OS will rebuild PERFLIB as necessary. 
            SafeRegistryHandle.RegCloseKey(RegistryKey.HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah i see, ok thank you! It makes sense that it wouldn't be something that is going to throw the exception then, I was mainly concerned with unpredictable situations but it seems like it can be controlled pretty well. Also, thanks for including the source code link!